# Redirect some URLs to https while keeping the rest http

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, ssl, https

As my site links are relative, i'm finding when i am in a https URL the rest of links become https.

So i want to use mod_rewrite to force redirect some URIs to *https* while keeping the rest of the website *http*.

I need something like:

*'Redirect actual url to http BUT If is contact.php then https, If is account then https, etc...'.*

Maybe someone can help me with this matter. Thanks!